# Alternative to using eval with jsonp response

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have the following response:

```
someFunc({"attr":"val"});
```

How do I retrieve a JSON fron it? I could remove the function name from the string and fetch only JSON, but I think it's not the best solution to JSONP. I could use `eval` to call the `someFunc` function, but then again, `eval` is bad. How should I do this?

Comment: The safe(r) solution is a case statement with allowed functions

Comment: How are you getting this value? Are you calling some remote resource? Usually you would define the `someFunc` function in your code and then feed the remote resource as `src` attribute of a `script` tag that you would inject dynamically into your DOM. Then the `someFunc` that you defined will automatically be called passing in the desired object as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Usually those kind of inputs are coming from a remote endpoints that your javascript application would call. The way that this remote call is usually done is by declaring a function with the expected name and then dynamically injecting a `script` tag into your DOM pointing its `src` property to the remote resource. When the resource is loaded it will call your function passing it as parameter the desired object.

Let's have an example. Suppose that you have a remote endpoint that returns this the data shown in your question.

Start by defining a function:

```
window.someFunc = function(result) {
    // result will represent the {"attr":"val"} object
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
};
```

and then just create a `script` element that would be appended to your DOM and initiate the JSONP retrieval from the remote endpoint:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/some_endpoint');
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

After the script successfully loads the remote resource it will invoke `someFunc` that you have defined and pass it the result object.

Remark: most JSONP enabled endpoints allow you to specify the name of the callback through some query string parameter: `http://example.com/some_endpoint?callback=someFunc` so that you know in advance how to name your function.